# Replace FCM Notification With Programmatically Created Notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have switched over to using `FCM` for my application. When my app is open, I handle the messages manually and if the `Fragment` which contains the message list isn't displayed, then I have the code display a `Notification`. To display the `Notification` I use the function:

```
public void notify(int id, Notification notification)
```

The problem I am encountering is if my application is in the background, `FCM` displays a `Notification`. I even set the `tag` parameter on the server so only one `Notification` will be displayed for the application. If the user opens the application without clicking on the `Notification`, and then received a message, a separate `Notification` is displayed, which is not what I want. I switched to using the function:

```
public void notify(String tag, int id, Notification notification)
```

And using the same `tag` as the server uses for the `FCM` message still produces a second notification. Is there a way the `Notification` I create programmatically can replace the `Notification` created by `FCM`?

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that FCM handles messages with pure `Notification` or `Data` payloads differently. Please check your message to see which kind you are sending and check Firebase documentation.

I had the issue of when I had a certain Activity running that I did not want to receive a Notification. So I created a static utility class that kept a boolean property indicating if that Activity was active. In my Notification receiver I check this value and either issued the notification or not. Like this:

My static utility class:

```
public class MyRunningActivity {

    private static boolean isActivityRunning = false;

    public static void setIsRunningActivity(boolean isRunning){
        isActivityRunning = isRunning;
    }

    public static boolean getIsRunningActivity(){
        return isActivityRunning;
    }
}
```

Within the class that receives the `onMessageReceived`:

```
   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String notification = "";
        String title = "";
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            title = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "title");
            notification = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "body");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            notification = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        }

        sendNotification(title, notification);
    }


private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
    try{

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        //Generate a new 'unique' request code -- this helps to refresh the activity if it is already active
        int requestCode = CodeGenerator.getRandomNumber(10, 10000);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

        // If the Activity is active then this will keep the notification from being sent
        // But the intent Extras will be delivered to the OnNewIntent method and handled there.
        // I had to put the singleTop flag in the Manifest, otherwise this will cause the
        // activity to close and reopen....
        try {
            if(MyRunningActivityUtility.getIsRunningActivity()) {
                    intent.putExtra("add_ring_tone","true");
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                              requestCode,
                                              intent,
                                              PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );

                    pendingIntent.send();
                    \\ !!! Notice that return here prevents the Notification from being sent !!!
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1){
            Log.e(TAG, ex1.getMessage());
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                  requestCode,
                                  intent,
                                  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder)
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.your_custom_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                        .setContentText(notificationBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int idNot = CodeGenerator.getRandomNumber(10, 10000);
        notificationManager.notify(idNot, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

There might be some things in this example you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are receiving FCM Notification messages:

> Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the
>   app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are
>   handled by these callbacks:
>
> didReceiveRemoteNotification: on iOS
>   onMessageReceived() on Android.

You should receive FCM Data messages instead and create the notification programatically:

> Client app is responsible for processing data messages.

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)